# Precondition for Camunda process in a REST application

Tags: java, camunda

In some cases when modeling a process with camunda one might have a precondition that has be to executed. If the precondition fails, the process instance should be stopped, returning an error event.

Now, the problem is that, once the process instance is started, you cannot return a mapped error code as an exception to the client who send the request, since an error can only be caugth with a listener.

```
public void createEntity(SomeEntity e) {
    repository.save(e);
    // start a workflow with camunda
    startWorkflow(e);

    /* 
     * If the precondition fails, it would be nice to throw an 
     * exception here, indicating 400 (Bad Request)
     */
}
```

If this is not possible, a simple solution would be to exclude that part from the workflow and only start it if the precondition is successful. But then, you cannot model the *complete* process with camunda, only a part of it. Returning 204 (No Content) and fetching the result of the process instance in a second query also seems wrong to me.

So, can you wait for a process instance to finish or at least return a mapped error code to the client within the request?